# SQL запрос или объединение данных

Tags: php, запрос, sql

Здравствуйте! Долго не могу разобраться с одной проблемой.
Дело в том, что мне нужно результат (цифры) сложить.

```
$sql = "SELECT `u`.`login` as `login`, `u`.`dostup` as `dostup`, `u`.`fac` as `fac`, SUM(`h`.`mark`) as `sumh`, COUNT(`h`.`id`) as `counth` FROM  `users` as `u`  LEFT JOIN `homework` as `h` ON (`u`.`login` = `h`.`student`) WHERE `u`.`fac` != '-' and `h`.`status` != '0' and `h`.`status` != '2' and `u`.`dostup` > 0  and `u`.`dostup` < 6 GROUP BY `u`.`id`  ORDER BY `sumh` DESC";
```

Помимо всего прочего, нужен вывод цифр "sumh", вывожу так:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { echo ".($rows['sumh'] ? $rows['sumh'] : 0).";}
```

Всё отлично, выводит. Далее, подобный запрос:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `u`.`login` as `login`, `u`.`dostup` as `dostup`, `u`.`fac` as `fac`, SUM(`r`.`mark`) as `sumr`, COUNT(`r`.`id`) as `counthr` FROM  `users` as `u`  LEFT JOIN `reports` as `r` ON (`u`.`login` = `r`.`student`) WHERE `u`.`fac` != '-' and `r`.`status` != '0' and `r`.`status` != '2' and `u`.`dostup` > 0  and `u`.`dostup` < 6 GROUP BY `u`.`id`  ORDER BY `sumr` DESC";

$res = mysql_query($sql) & mysql_query($sql2);
```

Нужно сложить результат суммы чисел первого запроса со вторым... Пытаюсь так, но не работает..

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { echo ".($rows['sumh'] ? $rows['sumh'] : 0) + ($rows['sumr'] ? $rows['sumr'] : 0)."; }
```

Что я делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Comment: Друг предложил устроить сложение в виде массивов, а я понятия не имею как это осуществить...

Answer (score 1):

Вы выводите строку, а не вычисляете значение.
Все дело в двойных кавычках у echo. Убрав эти кавычки все заработает как надо:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    echo ($rows['sumh'] ? $rows['sumh'] : 0) + ($rows2['sumr'] ? $rows2['sumr'] : 0);
}
```

P.s. Если я не ошибаюсь, то можно без этих условий писать, т.к. PHP преобразует NULL, false, '' к 0.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    echo $rows['sumh'] + $rows2['sumr'];
}
```

Единственное условие: **количество строк в выборках должно совпадать**

Comment: Не получается... быть обработка результата не корректна?
$res = mysql_query($sql) and mysql_query($sql2);

Comment: Да, видимо в этом.  
Исправил код